# Place node under bounding box of subfigures

Tags: tikz-pgf, bounding-box

I want to draw a figure that consists of two subfigures.

How can I place the labels (e.g. (a) and (b)) using bounding boxes?

Here is my code so far, but I am not getting anywhere.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}
            \draw(0,0) -- (0,2) -- (2,2)-- (2,0)-- cycle;
            \node [anchor=north] at (current bounding box.south) {(a)};
        \end{scope}     
        \begin{scope}[xshift = 3cm]
            \draw(0,0) -- (0,2) -- (2,2)-- (2,0)-- cycle;
            \node [anchor=north] at (current bounding box.south) {(b)};
        \end{scope}     
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My result:
[image]

I would like to have "(b)" centered under the right subfigure.

Any help is welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I found it!

For each scope I have to define a local bounding box and use the anchor for this particular box.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}[draw, local bounding box=bounding box 0]
            \draw(0,0) -- (0,2) -- (2,2)-- (2,0)-- cycle;
            \node [anchor=north] at (bounding box 0.south) {(a)};
        \end{scope}     
        \begin{scope}[draw, local bounding box=bounding box 1, xshift = 3cm]
            \draw(0,0) -- (0,2) -- (2,2)-- (2,0)-- cycle;
            \node [anchor=north] at (bounding box 1.south) {(b)};
        \end{scope}     
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Solved!

Answer (score 0):

Desired result I can reproduce with the following simple code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
N/.style = {draw, minimum size=20mm}
                    ]
\node (a)   [N, label=below:{(a)}] {};
\node (b)   [N, label=below:{(b)},
             right=20mm] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]